# consume only csv in rest service using jersey

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, csv, jersey

I m trying to send a csv file in post request and want to get the csv data at server.I am using jersey for creating web service.what should be the content type while sending csv file and what should be @consumes(**__**) annotation at server side
Please help

jersey code

```
@POST

@Consumes("text/plain")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String respondToPost(String incomingCsv) throws IOException {
   return incomingCsv;
}
```

csv file :

```
email,group_email
member1@visheshapps.uni.me,team3@visheshapps.uni.me
member2@visheshapps.uni.me,team3@visheshapps.uni.me
```

this returns :

```
----0246824681357ACXZabcxyz
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <startpart>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="root-fields"


----0246824681357ACXZabcxyz
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <group.csv>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="file attachment"; filename="group.csv"

email,group_email
member1@visheshapps.uni.me,team3@visheshapps.uni.me
member2@visheshapps.uni.me,team3@visheshapps.uni.me

----0246824681357ACXZabcxyz--
```

while I want only

```
email,group_email
member1@visheshapps.uni.me,team3@visheshapps.uni.me
member2@visheshapps.uni.me,team3@visheshapps.uni.me
```

I changed the code but now I m getting 415 unsupported media type.my app is hosted on google app engine

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String respondToPost(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream csv) throws IOException {
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(csv));
    List<String[]> rows = csvReader.readAll();
    return rows.get(1)[0];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `text\plain` mediatype to recieve the request and [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to parse your request body.

Comment: thanks,I tried your advice but could not get what I wanted , please see the updated question

Comment: well, you send the whole file. Not its content. For file upload see http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Comment: hey I m just a beginner here,I need further help.Please see the updated question

Comment: add the `jersey-multipart.jar` to your `pom.xml` and to your classpath.

Comment: originally, the post was about `csv` and `jersey`. Sorry, this is not discussion board and I cannot answer every question you may have during your development. If my answer helped - accept it and ask a new question about new problem.